# How to form the path file name with version using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, object

I would like to know how to form the pathname using nodejs

To set the filename `NewFile v1.1` always show as `NewFile v1`

`.1` seems to be missing

```
 const pathFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'NewFile v1.1');
// displays as NewFile v1
```

Expected Output

```
NewFile v1.1
```

Comment: Are you getting `NewFile v1` printed to console when you `console.log(pathFile)` in your program or when you attempt to write to `pathFile`?